Need an easy program to plot 3D vector fields
I need to draw a 3D electric field, so either a vector field plot (arrow length = field strength) or flow lines will do.
I do NOT do coding or programming, so no matplotlib, Matlab, Mathematica, Python, etc. In the past I’ve used Desmos to make 2D graphs and things.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

No Code
For plotting 3D vector field in Desmos, you can use something like Vector Field Grapher by Elliot Wymore. For the tool linked, you can simply specify the three components of the vector-valued function. You can also change the domain to plot, and the length and thinkness of the vectors.
Another project, based on GeoGebra, is Vector field 3D by Juan Carlos Ponce Campuzano. However, it is a bit worse than the previous option, since you only have the option to scale the entire plot, and the ticks of the axes doesn't even change with the scale.
One-liner
Although you specified that you do not want to write any code, the following options are pretty much just a single line of function call, and are not any more complicated than saying "the x component of the function is ..., and the y component is..., etc." in natural language. These are provided as backups in case you need finer controls or better-looking plots.
You can use the plot_vector_field3d() function in SageMath. Simply copy the two lines of example code linked in the documentation, which is also provided with annotation below into SageMathCell (It is online, so you don't need to do any local setup.), and change it to the function you want to plot.
# Declare the variables
x,y,z = var('x y z')
# The three components of the function,
# followed by the ranges of the x, y, and z axis in the input.
plot_vector_field3d((x*cos(z), -y*cos(z), sin(z)),
                     (x,0,pi), (y,0,pi), (z,0,pi))

If you have Mathematica (I tried the method below using WolframAlpha, but unfortunately it doesn't work.), you can simply use the function VectorPlot3D. Here is an example from the documentation:
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]

The first argument specifies the function you are plotting to be f(x) = <x, y, z>, while the following three arguments limits the x, y, and z axis to all be in [-1, 1].

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
